# Understanding functions with variable scoping

Tags: r, scoping

For this code :

```
A <- 100; B <- 20

f1 <- function(a) {
  B <- 100
  f2 <- function(b) {
    A <<- 200
    B <<- 1000
  }
  f2(a)
}

f1(B)
cat(A)
cat(B)
```

The following is the output :

```
> cat(A)
200
> cat(B)
20
```

Here is my understanding of above code : 
The function f1 is invoked with parameter B that has value 20. Within f1 a local variable B is created ( B <- 100 ), f1.B does not have an effect on the variable B 
initialiazed outside function call f1 as f1.B is locally scoped to the function f1. A new function f2 is created within f1 that accepts a single argument b. 
Within f1 the function f2 is invoked passing as paramter a to f2. f2 does not makes use of its argument b. f2 modifies A using the global operator <-- and sets it to 200. This
why cat(A) outputs 200.

My understanding is incorrect as B is set to 20 when I expect 1000 ? As A is set to 200 in f2 using <-- . d should same not also occur for B ?

Comment: Interesting. When you add a `print(B)` beneath the `f2(a)` and use `debug(f1)`, you see that `f2` changes the local `B`, prints `1000`, but leaves the global `B` unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The function f1 is invoked with parameter B that has value 20.

No, I don't think so. It is invoked with a parameter `a` that has the same value as the `B` in the global environment. `B` is not directly involved in this point.

You then assign a 100 to a different `B`, which you call `f1.B` in your post. (Note that, following the previous statement, that `B` is created here, not overwritten.)

Then when using the `<<-` operator, it traverses up in scope, going from `f2` (where no `B` exists) to `f1`, where it finds this "`f1.B`" and assigns a 1000.

Similarly, when using the `<<-` on `A`, it traverses up. It finds no `A` in either `f2` or `f1`, but does in the global environment and assigns it there.

You then print to old original `B`, which has never been altered.

From the help:

> `<<-` and `->>` (...) cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being
>   assigned. If such a variable is found (and its binding is not locked)
>   then its value is redefined, otherwise assignment takes place in the
>   global environment.

So for `B`, *"such a variable is found"*, while for `A` *"assignment takes place in the global environment."*

*Conclusion:* `<<-` is confusing, and often better to be avoided.

Comment: So `<<-` only traverses up one environment and tries to find the object, and continues up to the `.globalEnv` if no object is found before?

Comment: No, my understanding is that it traverses up through all parent environments, but will stop as soon as it has found a match.

Comment: That's what I meant :) Thanks, this is very insightful.

Comment: Ah yes, it "traverses up one environment" _at a time_.